# getFloat of SharedPreferences not saving good values

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have a little game and I need to store some score information and some data if a stage is open or closed. I tried with externalstorage, internal storage and now with shared preferences. 
My game has only one activity and  screens. A screen has a methond called pause which is called when we change the screen and also at the end when onPause is called too.
I put the save method in every screen but no succes.
My class GameImpl extends Activity.
so I called the method load and save it a GameImpl instance which is the same in every class screen that I have. The code in class Settigs.java is below with the two methods load and save:

```
package com.spaceguardians;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;

public class Settings {
public static int           Open                = 1;
public static int           Locked              = 0;
public static final int     NR_STAGES           = 8;
public static final float   NOT_PLAYED          = 0;

public static int           planet1             = Open;
public static int           planet2             = Locked;
public static int           planet3             = Locked;
public static int           planet4             = Locked;
public static int[]         stagePlanet1        = { Open, Locked, Locked, Locked, Locked, Locked, Locked, Locked };
public static int[]         stagePlanet2        = { Locked, Locked, Locked, Locked, Locked, Locked, Locked, Locked };
public static int[]         stagePlanet3        = { Locked, Locked, Locked, Locked, Locked, Locked, Locked, Locked };
public static int[]         stagePlanet4        = { Locked, Locked, Locked, Locked, Locked, Locked, Locked, Locked };
public static float[]       stagePlanet1Score   = { 00.00f, NOT_PLAYED, NOT_PLAYED, NOT_PLAYED, NOT_PLAYED,
        NOT_PLAYED, NOT_PLAYED, NOT_PLAYED      };
public static float[]       stagePlanet2Score   = { NOT_PLAYED, NOT_PLAYED, NOT_PLAYED, NOT_PLAYED, NOT_PLAYED,
        NOT_PLAYED, NOT_PLAYED, NOT_PLAYED      };
public static float[]       stagePlanet3Score   = { NOT_PLAYED, NOT_PLAYED, NOT_PLAYED, NOT_PLAYED, NOT_PLAYED,
        NOT_PLAYED, NOT_PLAYED, NOT_PLAYED      };
public static float[]       stagePlanet4Score   = { NOT_PLAYED, NOT_PLAYED, NOT_PLAYED, NOT_PLAYED, NOT_PLAYED,
        NOT_PLAYED, NOT_PLAYED, NOT_PLAYED      };

public static boolean       soundEnabled        = true;

public static final String spaceGuardiansPref = "spaceGuardiansPref" ;

public static void load(Context context) {// FileIO files) {

    SharedPreferences mySharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(spaceGuardiansPref,
            Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    soundEnabled = mySharedPreferences.getBoolean("sound", true);
    planet1 = mySharedPreferences.getInt("planet1", Open);
    planet2 = mySharedPreferences.getInt("planet2", Locked);
    planet3 = mySharedPreferences.getInt("planet3", Locked);
    planet4 = mySharedPreferences.getInt("planet4", Locked);

    for (int i = 0; i < Settings.NR_STAGES; i++) {
        if (i == 0) {
            Settings.stagePlanet1[i] = mySharedPreferences.getInt("stagePlanet1" + i, Open);
            Settings.stagePlanet1Score[i] = mySharedPreferences.getFloat("stagePlanet1Score", 0);
        } else {
            Settings.stagePlanet1[i] = mySharedPreferences.getInt("stagePlanet1" + i, Locked);
            Settings.stagePlanet1Score[i] = mySharedPreferences.getFloat("stagePlanet1Score", NOT_PLAYED);
        }
        Settings.stagePlanet2[i] = mySharedPreferences.getInt("stagePlanet2" + i, Locked);
        Settings.stagePlanet2Score[i] = mySharedPreferences.getFloat("stagePlanet2Score", NOT_PLAYED);

        Settings.stagePlanet3[i] = mySharedPreferences.getInt("stagePlanet3" + i, Locked);
        Settings.stagePlanet3Score[i] = mySharedPreferences.getFloat("stagePlanet3Score", NOT_PLAYED);

        Settings.stagePlanet4[i] = mySharedPreferences.getInt("stagePlanet4" + i, Locked);
        Settings.stagePlanet4Score[i] = mySharedPreferences.getFloat("stagePlanet4Score", NOT_PLAYED);

    }

}

public static void save(Context context) {// FileIO files) {
    SharedPreferences mySharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(spaceGuardiansPref,
            Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mySharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("sound", soundEnabled);
    editor.putInt("planet1", planet1);
    editor.putInt("planet2", planet2);
    editor.putInt("planet3", planet3);
    editor.putInt("planet4", planet4);
    for (int i = 0; i < Settings.NR_STAGES; i++) {
        editor.putInt("stagePlanet1" + i, Settings.stagePlanet1[i]);
        editor.putFloat("stagePlanet1Score" + i, Settings.stagePlanet1Score[i]);

        editor.putInt("stagePlanet2" + i, Settings.stagePlanet2[i]);
        editor.putFloat("stagePlanet2Score" + i, Settings.stagePlanet2Score[i]);

        editor.putInt("stagePlanet3" + i, Settings.stagePlanet3[i]);
        editor.putFloat("stagePlanet3Score" + i, Settings.stagePlanet3Score[i]);

        editor.putInt("stagePlanet4" + i, Settings.stagePlanet4[i]);
        editor.putFloat("stagePlanet4Score" +i, Settings.stagePlanet4Score[i]);
    }
    editor.commit();
```

}

For now I believe just the score is not displaying propretly. The sound is ok, It save the state and the stages/planets are oppend and closed correctly but the score is 00.00 for all the stages that are open. I do not know why..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that you are appending `i` to your score preference name when saving it:

```
editor.putFloat("stagePlanet4Score" +i, Settings.stagePlanet4Score[i]);
                                   ^^^
```

But you are not adding it when loading the score:

```
Settings.stagePlanet4Score[i] =
    mySharedPreferences.getFloat("stagePlanet4Score", NOT_PLAYED);
                                                   ^^
```